# Sort only one column with jquery and tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

At the moment im using jquery tablesorter and tablesorter filter. My problem is that i want that my filter would filter only one column. Now its filtering all columns. You can see my site here: http://tinyurl.com/3j38vye

Now its filtering all colums and i'd like to filter only "Lainasumma" column. Could you also say why its not sorting amounts properly?

Answer (score 8):

Did you look at the [documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Configuration)? [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/9kQcJ/) of how you would disable some columns that use tablesorter. You can pass a `headers` object in which you can specify which columns are disabled.

An alternate method is to add `class="{sorter: false}"` to the cells on which you want to disable the sorting.

## Edit

You can use `$.tablesorter.addParser()` method to define custom sorting (see the jsFiddle example above).

## Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'custom_sort_function',
        is: function(s) {
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s) {
            // the € symbol causes the tablesorter to treat the value as a string
            // remove it and let the tablesorter treat it as numeric
            // use /\u20AC/ instead of /€/ if regex does not work as expected
            return s.replace(/€/, '');
        },
        type: 'numeric'
    });
    $("#pikavipit").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            0: {
                sorter: false
            },
            1: {
                sorter: false
            },
            2: {
                sorter: 'custom_sort_function'
            },
            3: {
                sorter: false
            },
            4: {
                sorter: false
            },
            5: {
                sorter: false
            },
            6: {
                sorter: false
            },
            7: {
                sorter: false
            },
            8: {
                sorter: false
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, that was awesome. Now one problem is solved. Still wondering why tablesorter isnt' sorting right those money values.

Comment: It is treating them as strings and sorting them as string where 1000€ comes before 200€. tablesorter allows you to define your own custom sorting function. Again, consult the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest solution for that is to modify the selectorHeaders in the javascript file and set it to something other like:

```
 selectorHeaders: 'thead th.sortable'
```

Now, the only thing you have to do is to give only the collumns you want to be sortable the css class sortable.

Comment: Nice answer! You should be able to pass that option in to avoid editing the plugin e.g. `$( '.yourTable' ).tablesorter( { selectorHeaders: 'thead th.sortable' } );`

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that it is not sorting the amounts properly because the sorting don't treat the amounts columns as numbers and instead it treats them as text so it is sorting them text based.

Comment: is it possible to sort them as amounts?

Comment: If the jquery tablesorter and tablesorter filter support this.