# JQuery TableSorter: How to show the arrows on one column only

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table, tablesorter

I am implementing ***jquery's*** ***tablesorter***.
But I can't seem to find a way to do the following:

1. Only show the sorting arrows on one column
2. Only permit sorting the table by clicking on that column only, and when
   clicking on other columns do nothing.

I Googled a lot but to no avail.

this is my table:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849558/sort-only-one-column-with-jquery-and-tablesorter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look here http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Configuration

at the header property